# React-router <Link> not working with data-toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-router

I am trying to use React, React-Router, and bootstrap to define a pill-based navigation bar. I define the nav bar like this:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <ul className="nav nav-pills">
        <li className="active"><Link data-toggle="tab" to="/test/vocabulary">Vocabulary</Link></li>
        <li><Link data-toggle="tab" to="/test/noun">Noun</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <div className="tab-content">
        <div id="vocabulary" className="tab-pane fade in active">
          <TestVocabularyView/>
        </div>
        <div id="noun" className="tab-pane fade">
          <TestNounView/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the "data-toggle" aspect of the `<Link>`. When I click on the pill header, I see this in the browser console:

```
jquery.js:1491 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
#/test/nounSizzle.error @ jquery.js:1491Sizzle.tokenize @
jquery.js:2108Sizzle.select @ jquery.js:2512Sizzle @    
jquery.js:888jQuery.fn.extend.find @ jquery.js:2728jQuery.fn.init @ 
jquery.js:2845jQuery @ jquery.js:73Tab.show @ bootstrap.js:2096(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:2169jQuery.extend.each @ 
jquery.js:384jQuery.fn.jQuery.each @ jquery.js:136Plugin @ 
bootstrap.js:2164clickHandler @ bootstrap.js:2193jQuery.event.dispatch @ 
jquery.js:4665elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4333
```

My routes are setup like this:

```
<Route path="test" component={TestView}>
  <Route path="vocabulary" component={TestVocabularyView}/>
  <Route path="noun" component={TestNounView}/>
</Route>
```

When I hover the mouse over the "Noun" pill header, I see this URL: `http://localhost:3000/#/test/noun`

I am using browserHistory.

Comment: I don't think you can plug in Bootstrap just like that. Have you tried something like [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)?

Comment: My eventual "solution": instead of trying to route to the individual tabs, I instead used an onClick function to tab("show") the appropriate tab.  This works fine, at the cost of not being able to access the tab panes through URLs.

Comment: Looking through the bootstrap code, I discovered that it specifically looks for <a> tags.  So the special React-Router <Link> tags are definitely part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing

```
<li><Link data-toggle="tab" to="/test/noun">Noun</Link></li>
```

I did this:

```
<li data-toggle="tab"><Link to="/test/noun">Noun</Link></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70291878/6665507) and what helped me is

1. wrapping the `<li>` with the `<Link>` component and
2. adding the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute to the `<li>`

```html
<ul className="nav nav-pills">
   <Link to="/test/vocabulary">
      <li className="active" data-toggle="tab">Vocabulary</li>
   </Link>
   <Link to="/test/noun">
      <li data-toggle="tab">Noun</li>
   </Link>
</ul>
```